# Implement delegate using generic protocol in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create a delegate protocol that implements a function which passes an array of a generic type. I've tried several combinations but none of them seem to do the trick.

This is the most approximate thing i've reached to. This is the protocol:

```
     protocol APIControllerProtocol {

          typealias T

          func didReceiveAPIResults(results: [T])
     }
```

And this is the the delegator object:

```
    class APIController<U:APIControllerProtocol> {

         typealias ElementType = U
         var delegate: ElementType?

         init(delegate: ElementType){

             self.delegate = delegate

         }

         func getAPIResults(){

              // Perform some action before delegation
              // "results" is an Array of dictionaries got from NSJSONSerialization

              self.delegate?.didReceiveAPIResults(results.map{dict in Album(json:dict)})

         }

     }
```

However, the last line get this error: "Album is not convertible to U.T"

"Album" is the model object used to return the results.

What am i doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Following [Mike S advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25732775/implement-delegate-using-generic-protocol-in-swift/25734549#25734549), i've made the protocol method `didReceiveAPIResults` a generic function, and specified what `T` is in the delegate. However, when receiving and assigning the argument of type T to a property in the delegate, i get the error: "T is not identical to T"

```
class TestDelegate: APIControllerProtocol {
    typealias T = Album
    var albums:[T] = [T]()

    func didReceiveAPIResults<T>(results: [T]) {
        // ...

        self.albums = results //ERROR: "T is not identical to T"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `didReceiveAPIResults` declaration in `APIControllerProtocol` needs to be a generic function so that the generic type `T` is passed along to it correctly.

```
protocol APIControllerProtocol {
    typealias T

    func didReceiveAPIResults<T>(results: [T])
}
```

**Note:** This means your delegate definition will need to define what `T` is:

```
class TestDelegate: APIControllerProtocol {
    typealias T = Album

    func didReceiveAPIResults<T>(results: [T]) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

---

***Update:** While the code above does get rid of the original error, it turns out that it acts more like a workaround and doesn't really address the root of the problem.*

The real issue seems to be that the compiler is having trouble reconciling what `U.T` is with no ambiguity. That's actually easy enough to fix though, we just need to give it a more precise definition *(note the `where` clause in the `APIController` definition)*:

```
protocol APIControllerProtocol {
    typealias T
    func didReceiveAPIResults(results: [T])
}

class APIController<U:APIControllerProtocol where U.T == Album> {
    typealias ElementType = U
    // ...
}
```

***Note:** I removed the `<T>` that I added to the function in the protocol previously; that's not needed anymore and will end up causing problems later.*

With that, the `TestDelegate` class works as expected (you don't even need the `typealias` anymore):

```
class TestDelegate: APIControllerProtocol {
    var albums: [Album]? = nil

    func didReceiveAPIResults(results: [Album]) {
        albums = results
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've edited the question with your advice, however i get an error: "T is not identical to T" when trying to assign the method argument to a property in the delegate (see edited question for further detail). Maybe this is a very basic Generics issue, but i'm really lost here...

Comment: Sorry, it looks like I initially lead you astray. I updated the answer with a better solution.

Comment: Thank you so much, i really appreciate the help. I've marked your answer as the right answer (i'm new around here so let me know if there is anything else i should do). I have one more question, though, do you think it's possible to make the delegator (APIController) agnostic to the 'Album' type? I mean i'd like to use the same APIController to perform tasks with different kind of objects, and delegate the processing of the results to delegate objects that will know how to manage the model type (Album, or Track, or whatever). I'm not 100% sure if that makes sense, anyway

Comment: Finally, by using AnyObject instead of Album i think i've addressed that last question i've made. I guess i could use some base object common to all my model objects. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Glad I could help! I would recommend using a common base class for your Album, Track, etc. Objects. Mainly because the more specific you are about your definitions, the more Swift's type safety can help you out and less issues you'll run in to.